# How do I put a previous game button for my tictactoe?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a tictactoe game but there is a twist.

I need to have a button that show the previous game history or the winning pattern for the player.
what I am thinking is to manipulate the nth child of my data-cell so that it will be stored in a variable every time a player clicks on a cell on the board and when the previous game button is clicked, all the variables will be displayed again in the board.

```
<div class="board" id="board">
    <div class="cell" id="c0" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c1" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c2" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c3" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c4" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c5" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c6" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c7" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c8" data-cell></div>
</div>






 const X = 'x';
const CIRCLE = 'circle';
const WIN_COMB = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
]
var previousMoves = []

const cellElements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cell]');
const board = document.getElementById('board');
const winnerDeclare = document.getElementById('winnerMsg');
const winnerMessage = document.querySelector('[data-winning-message-text]');
const xScore = document.getElementById('xScore');
const oScore = document.getElementById('oScore');
const drawScore = document.getElementById('draws');
const scoreReset = document.getElementById('resetScore');
const prevMatch = document.getElementById('previous');
const reset = document.getElementById('restart');
let circle;

var scoreX = 0;
var scoreO = 0;
var scoreDraw = 0;

gameStart()
reset.addEventListener('click', gameStart);
scoreReset.addEventListener('click', scoreClear);
// prevMatch.addEventListener('click', savedGame);

function gameStart(){
    circle = false;
    cellElements.forEach(cell => {
        cell.classList.remove(X);
        cell.classList.remove(CIRCLE);
        cell.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
        cell.addEventListener('click',handleClick,{ once: true});
    })
    setHover();
    winnerDeclare.classList.remove('show');
    
}

function handleClick(e){
    // placing the mark on the board
    const cell = e.target;
    const currentClass = circle ? CIRCLE : X;
    placemark(cell,currentClass);
    if (checkwin(currentClass)){
        endGame(false);
    } else if(isDraw()) {
        endGame(true);
    } else {
        swapTurns();
        setHover();
    } 
}

function endGame(draw){
    if (draw){
        winnerMessage.innerText = "DRAW!"
        // draw counter
        scoreDraw++;
        drawScore.innerHTML = scoreDraw;
    } else if (circle == true) {
        winnerMessage.innerText = "O is the winner!";
        scoreO++;
        oScore.innerHTML = scoreO;
    } else {
        winnerMessage.innerText = "X is the winner!"
        scoreX++;
        xScore.innerHTML = scoreX;
    }
    winnerDeclare.classList.add('show');
    
}

// declare draw
function isDraw() {
    return [...cellElements].every(cell =>{
        return cell.classList.contains(X) || cell.classList.contains(CIRCLE)
    })
}

function placemark(cell, currentClass) {
    cell.classList.add(currentClass);
    // previousMoves = cell.classList.add(currentClass);
}

// switching turns from X to O 
function swapTurns(){
    circle = !circle;
}

// for hover effect
function setHover() {
    board.classList.remove(X);
    board.classList.remove(CIRCLE);

    if (circle) {
        board.classList.add(CIRCLE);
    } else {
        board.classList.add(X);
    }
}

// winner check
function checkwin(currentClass){
    return WIN_COMB.some(combination =>{
        return combination.every(index =>{
            return cellElements[index].classList.contains(currentClass);
        })
    })
}

// reset scoreboard
function scoreClear() {
    scoreX = 0;
    scoreO = 0;
    scoreDraw = 0;

    drawScore.innerText = "";
    oScore.innerText = "";
    xScore.innerText = "";
}

// // save previous game
// function saveTheGame(){
//     const cellHolder = []
//    for(x=0; x <= length.previousMoves;x++){
//        cellHolder[x] = document.getElementById("c" + [x]);
//        previousMoves[x] = cellHolder[x];
//    }
   
// }
// function savedGame() {
//   for(i=0; length.previousMoves;i++){
//       cellElements.innerHTML = previousMoves[i];
//   }
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a global variable with the `Array` type, and any time a game ends, you would `push` there the game status. Maybe simply "O", "X" or "D" for draw, or if required, an object containing the endgame as one field and the entire board state as another field.

Then you'd read the last value in this array to display the last game, or do some computation across the entire array for statistics and patterns.

For Instance:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _e => {
  //Mimic your own variables
  const winnerMessage = document.querySelector('.winner-message');
  const winnerDeclare = winnerMessage;
  const xScore = document.querySelector('.x-score');
  const oScore = document.querySelector('.o-score');
  const drawScore = document.querySelector('.d-score');
  let circle = false;
  let scoreO = 0, scoreX = 0, scoreDraw = 0;
  
  //New one for storing endgame states
  const prevGames = [];

  function endGame(draw) {
    let gameResult;
    if (draw) {
      winnerMessage.innerText = "DRAW!"
      // draw counter
      scoreDraw++;
      drawScore.innerHTML = scoreDraw;
      gameResult = "D";
    } else if (circle == true) {
      winnerMessage.innerText = "O is the winner!";
      scoreO++;
      oScore.innerHTML = scoreO;
      gameResult = "O";
    } else {
      winnerMessage.innerText = "X is the winner!"
      scoreX++;
      xScore.innerHTML = scoreX;
      gameResult = "X";
    }
    winnerDeclare.classList.add('show');

    prevGames.push({
      result: gameResult,
      boardState: boardState()
    });
  }

  function boardState() {
    const res = new Array(9);
    document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(cell => {
      id = cell.id;
      index = parseInt(id.substr(1));
      res[index] = cell.textContent;
    });
    return res;
  }

  document.querySelector('#btn-prevstate').addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (prevGames.length) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(prevGames[prevGames.length - 1]));
    } else {
      alert('No previous game');
    }
  });
  
  //For testing only
  document.querySelector('#btn-simgame').addEventListener('click', e => {
    circle = Math.random() < .5;
    document.querySelectorAll('.cell').forEach(cell => {
      cell.textContent = (Math.random() < .5) ? 'O' : 'X';
    });
    endGame(Math.random() < .5);
  });
});
```

```css
#board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 2em);
  grid-auto-rows: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.scores {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="board" id="board">
    <div class="cell" id="c0" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c1" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c2" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c3" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c4" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c5" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c6" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c7" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" id="c8" data-cell></div>
</div>

<div class="my-stuff-for-js">
  <p class="winner-message"></p>
  <div class="scores">
    <p class="x-score">0</p>
    <p class="o-score">0</p>
    <p class="d-score">0</p>
  </div>

  <button id="btn-simgame">Sim game</button>
  <button id="btn-prevstate">Show prev state</button>
</div>
```

*Sorry, answer based on previous version of your question, but it still stands*